# PHP Subscribe Form with Email Duplicate Check

Tags: php, forms

I'm very new to PHP and struggling with adding in duplicate email check with this code

This works as I need in terms of pushing info to mysql db but I want it to not allow duplicate emails. I was looking at adding a count for the results which match the inputted email and then if >1 flag as duplicate. I'm not sure where this should go in the flow or how to do it to be honest. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //collect form data
    extract($_POST);

    if(!isset($error)){

        try {
            //insert into database
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO email_subs (email) VALUES (:email)') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':email' => $email
            ));

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: ./thanks.php?action=added');
            exit;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
}
?>
<form action='' method='post'>

<input type='email' name='email' required="required" data-error="Valid email is required." value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email'];}?>'></p>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter your email.
     </div>
    <button type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' class="btn-red">Sign-Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: set the `email` column as a unique key in the db table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first set the `email` column as a unique key in the db table

Then Check your PDOException

```
try {
   $prep->execute($values);
   // do other things if successfully inserted
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
      $email_error = "Email already exists in our mailing list"
      // then show this in html
   } else {

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have changed the db for email to be unique which is meaning it wont pass. I am finding that it just reloads the page but i'd like it to just show error "duplicate email". I think the best method would be to check against the DB first before it tries to pass into the DB. Does that make sense?

Comment: to perform the check without reloading the page then you'll need to use an ajax ( or `fetch` ) function

Comment: Thank you for all the help on this. I'm starting to enjoy PHP a bit even though im very early and basic. I will search on the fetch function as i'd rather prevent reload as it isn't good UX. Thanks again

Comment: Best of luck bro :-)